# Returning a dynamic array from a function

Tags: arrays, delphi, delphi-7

I'm working with Delphi 7.

Here's my base class. The function **load_for_edit()** is supposed to return an array of strings which sounds like it does. The problem is not particularly here but further.

```
    ...

type
    TStringArray = array of string;

    ...

    function load_for_edit(): TStringArray;

    ...

    numberOfFields: integer;

    ...

function TBaseForm.load_for_edit(): TStringArray;
var
    query: TADOQuery;
    i: integer;
begin
    query := TADOQuery.Create(self);
    query.Connection := DataModule1.ADOConnection;
    query.SQL.Add('CALL get_' + self.table_name + '_id(' + self.id + ')');
    query.Open;

    numberOfFields := query.Fields.Count;
    SetLength(result, query.Fields.Count);
    for i := 0 to query.Fields.Count - 1 do
        result[i] := query.Fields[i].Value.AsString;
end;
```

Next is the class that is a descendant of the base class and it's trying to receive an array from the base class's **load_for_edit()** function.

```
    ...

type
    TStringArray = array of string;

    ...

procedure TPublisherEditForm.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
    rec: TStringArray;
begin
    inherited;
    SetLength(rec, self.numberOfFields);
    rec := load_for_edit();                 // Compilation stops here
end;
```

But, the application won't compile. Delphi spits out this error message:

```
Incompatible types
```

So, what this means is that the function **load_for_edit()** returns a data type that is different from the variable **rec**'s data type, though, as can be seen from their respective type declaration sections, their declarations are absolutely identical. I don't know what's going on here and what to do. Please, help me come up with a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got two separate declarations of `TStringArray` (one in each unit), and they are *not* the same. (The fact that they're in two separate units makes them different. `UnitA.TStringArray` is not the same as `UnitB.TStringArray`, even if they're both declared as `type TStringArray = array of string;`.)

You need to use a single type declaration:

```
unit
  BaseFormUnit;

interface

uses
  ...
type
  TStringArray: array of string;

  TBaseForm = class(...)
    numberOfFields: Integer;
    function load_for_edit: TStringArray;
  end;

implementation

// Not sure here. It looks like you should use a try..finally to
// free the query after loading, but if you need to use it later
// to save the edits you should create it in the TBaseForm constructor
// and free it in the TBaseForm destructor instead, which means it
// should also be a field of the class declaration above.
function TBaseForm.load_for_edit(): TStringArray;
var
  query: TADOQuery;
  i: integer;
begin
  query := TADOQuery.Create(self);
  query.Connection := DataModule1.ADOConnection;
  query.SQL.Add('CALL get_' + self.table_name + '_id(' + self.id + ')');
  query.Open;

  numberOfFields := query.Fields.Count;
  SetLength(result, numberOfFields);
  for i := 0 to numberOfFields - 1 do
    Result[i] := query.Fields[i].Value.AsString;
end;
...
end.
```

Now your descendant class can access it:

```
unit
  PublisherEditFormUnit;

interface

uses
  ...  // Usual Forms, Windows, etc.
  BaseFormUnit;

type
  TPublisherEditForm = class(TBaseForm)
  ...
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
  end;

implementation

procedure TPublisherEditForm.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  rec: TStringArray;
begin
  // No need to call SetLength - the base class does.
  rec := load_for_edit();                 // Compilation stops here
end;
...
end.
```

Comment: You are correct about the double declarations being the problem, but your example is wrong. In your example, `TPublisherEditForm` does not derive from `TBaseForm`, but in Mikhail's situation it does. That makes a difference, because `TStringArray` does not need to be in a separate unit. It can be declared in the `TBaseForm` unit, and then `TPublisherEditForm` will have access to `TStringArray` because it has to `uses` the `TBaseForm` unit anyway.

Comment: @Remy: Thanks, I missed that. Rewrote example to show that instead, and corrected text.

Comment: This type identity is another issue that makes TArray<T> so useful in modern Delphi

Comment: @David: Agreed, but the question says Delphi 7, so that's not an option. :-) Not sure I agree with "another issue" though; the strong typing in Delphi has always been an advantage, IMO. (Rephrased to remove unintentional pun. <g>)

Comment: Almost all languages that I know are strongly typed, even dynamic languages like Python. In this case the type compatibility is an inconvenience to the programmer. In order for generics to be of any use at all TArray<T>'s type compatibility rules had to be special. In fact all generic types have special compatibility rules. Expect a diatribe when dmitry arrives.

Comment: So, when is this an issue? Imagine two libraries that operate with string arrays? Unless both use the same type that would need to be declared in rtl, you cannot use the two libraries in concert. Generic array solves this. More seriously, if you want to use third party library in concert with generic container, say using its ToArray method, again you need generic array. Dmitry will say that type compat should be relaxed for all dynamic arrays. He's correct that there is a problem. My opinion is that generic array is the better solution.

Comment: @Lucas: It works fine with array of record. I can't explain why *your code* isn't working, because I can't see it.

Comment: Nah forget it, after a 1h debuging the problem was another, thanks anyway. I thought the problem was with the record because every example you for some reason uses string